# Filling a 2D array with values from a 1D array, but using list comprehension

Tags: python, numpy, nested, list-comprehension, enumerate

I'm trying to "paste" the values contained in the 1D array *dataslice* (1x8) into the 2D array *values_matrix* (9x9), following the position indices contained in the array *setup* (8x2):

[image: desired result]

It's easy enough with a double *for* loop, but I want to be able to do this in one line using list comprehension.

However, my current code returns the error

```
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

referring to the "i" in `if i == setup[i][0]`, so I'm obviously missing something about how this works.

```py
import numpy as np

n = 9
setup = np.array([(3, 8),(5, 8),(4, 6),(4, 4),(2, 4),(6, 4),(3, 0),(5, 0)])
dataslice = np.array([ 1.82907198,  1.69794981,  1.30089053, -0.00452952,  2.32777365,  0.69508469,  2.06540834,  2.1184028 ])

values_matrix = np.zeros((n,n))
values_matrix = [j for i, j in (enumerate(dataslice) if i == setup[i][0] else 0)]
```

Could anyone tell me why I can't refer back to the "i" defined at the start of the list comprehension line later in this line?

Also, I know that I need to use nested list comprehension for the 2D "paste" operation, but I'm still in the learning phase and haven't figured that out yet, hence why my code above doesn't do this yet.

**EDIT**: @obchardon came up with a much better approach using indexing, I just had to adapt the "coordinates" in *dataslice*:

```
setup = np.array([(0, 3),(0, 5),(2, 4),(4, 4),(4, 2),(4, 6),(8, 3),(8, 5)])
values_matrix[setup[:,0],setup[:,1]] = dataslice
```

Comment: Use indexing instead: `values_matrix[setup[:,0],setup[:,1]] = dataslice`

Comment: Also by doing `values_matrix = [anything inside this array]` you overwrite the initial `values_matrix` array. Maybe that you should read the doc about numpy array indexing.

Comment: You are using `i` in the `for` clause. Try `(enumerate(dataslice))` (close the bracket).

Comment: @obchardon Yes, indexing works much better! Thanks! I've edited my post with the code that ended up working. How do I indicate this question as solved though? The button for this disappeared :/